# MojoFailureException caused by charsetName on Maven Archetype

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, encode, maven-archetype

When I try to run the command `mvn archetype:create-from-project` for my WAR project, this exception is showed after the reading of a .java file:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:create-from-project (default-cli) on project ConfiguradorWAR: charsetName -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:create-from-project (default-cli) on project ConfiguradorWAR: charset
Name
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: charsetName
        at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateArchetypeFromProjectMojo.execute(CreateArchetypeFromProjectMojo.java:285)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
```

The default project encode is **Cp1252**, I already tried **UTF-8** and **ISO-8859-1**, also edited the encode option from the project and eclipse preferences. On pom.xml:

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding> 
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <project.resources.sourceEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</project.resources.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

and

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <defaultEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</defaultEncoding>
        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
        <archetypeArtifactId>archetype-wsjpa</archetypeArtifactId>
                        <archetypeGroupId>br.com.example</archetypeGroupId>
                        <archetypeVersion>1.0</archetypeVersion>                              <archetypeFilteredExtentions>java,xml</archetypeFilteredExtentions>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
 <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.1</version>
     <configuration>
         <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
     </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

The best advice I got from my co-workers was try to replace all the characters with accent in the whole project. I have an EJB project with Cp1252 encode as default that worked on the first try. 
Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

After exhaustively exercite every param possible for the command line I found out the right one.

You should create your archetype like this:

```
mvn archetype:create-from-project -Darchetype.encoding=ISO-8859-1
```

As you can see on [Maven Archetype Plugin Docs](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/create-from-project-mojo.html) you should use the "User property archetype.encoding".

Any other parameter name will fail.

It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <project.resources.sourceEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</project.resources.sourceEncoding>
```

I needed to add the above. Also I ran mvn clean before running mvn archetype:create-from-project